# Questions about Dancing Links/Algorithm X

Tags: algorithm, sudoku

I'm working on making a sudoku app, and one of the things needed is a way to solve the sudoku. I did a lot of research on some backtracking algorithms, including making my own version, but then came across Dancing Links and Algorithm X. I've seen a few implementations of it, and it looks really cool, but had some questions - I can't quite wrap my head around it fully yet (I don't have much experience coding, so I haven't grasped all of what's needed to fully understand the core of it and how it works, though I am using [this](https://garethrees.org/2007/06/10/zendoku-generation/#section-4.2) as a handy reference)

As far as I understand, you have a sudoku, which you then convert to an array of 1s and 0s - the end goal of which is to find a combinations of rows that will be fully 1s - that then means we've found a valid solution (yay!)

Now, I kinda sorta understand how that works on normal sudokus - for example, if we put a 5 in the top left cell, it removes all the other options along that row and column, and in turn also removes all options of a 5 being in that square too. But what I don't quite understand is if I'm doing a sudoku variation, how will it work? For example, one popular type of variation is X-Sudoku, where, on top of the normal rules, you have to have the numbers 1 to 9 once on each of the main diagonals. Can I just pretend there's an extra 2 rows/columns on the sudoku that also need to be filled from 1-9 and do it that way, or does it not work like that?

Now, the hard question: another variant is anti-knight sudoku. Basically, on top of the normal rules, you can't have the same number a chess knight's move away (2 out and 1 to the side). Since this now gets a bit wonky in terms of the rows and whatnot, can these be added as extra constraints to the algorithm to solve sudokus along these lines?

Comment: Knuth volume 4 has a complete section on dancing links, including sudokus.

Comment: I just had a read through most of it, and while there weren't specific talks of how to solve sudoku variants like what I'm after at the moment, being able to read the concept in detail has helped me understand it a bit more, even though it's definitely a lot to get my head around. I've just got to figure out how to make it work with the code I've got at the moment, which is going to be the tricky part for sure, especially since I'm not great at JS :P

Answer (score 3):

X-Sudoku can be solved exactly the way you describe.

Anti-knight Sudoku is trickier because the anti-knight constraint does not fit as straightforwardly into the exact cover framework. There's an extension of Algorithm X that handles packing constraints (at most one instead of exactly one) efficiently by treating them as satisfied when choosing an unsatisfied constraint. Then for each triple of consisting of a digit and two squares a knight's jump apart, you have a packing constraint that at most one of those squares is filled with that digit.

If implementing Algorithm X seems like too much of a challenge, you could look into finding a SAT solver library instead.

Comment: That's fair enough about X-Sudoku - I'll just have to figure out how to do it!

As for anti-knight sudoku, do you know where I can find out a bit about it? I haven't seen anything about adding in packing constraints. I take it I can then also use this on any type of constraint I want as well?

For Algorithm X though, I managed to find a JavaScript version that I was able to implement - I don't necessarily 100% understand it fully enough to add extra constraints, but I'll have to give it a shot to figure it out.

Comment: @Opaquer Exact cover works on 0-1 variables and constraints like x111 + x112 + ... + x119 = 1 (if xijk is the 0-1 variable indicating that square (i, j) has value k, then this constraint expresses the fact that this square has exactly one value; a column constraint might be x175 + x275 + ... + x975 = 1, which says that column 7 has at most one 5). Packing constraints would be like x175 + x255 ≤ 1 (square (1, 7) isn't 5 or square (2, 5) isn't 5; we have one of these constraints for each possible conflict). You can write packing constraints by introducing a slack variable: x175 + x255 + s = 1.

Comment: @Opaquer the problem is that Algorithm X doesn't handle that particularly efficiently. Better to modify the implementation instead so that when it's looking for an unsatisfied constraint it chooses one of the equality constraints.

Comment: OK, so this is pushing the limits of my knowledge of exact cover problems and Algorithm X, but so far it's making sense I think. When you mention about the slack variable, s, would that just if neither square 1, 7 or 2, 5 are a 5, that putting a 5 in there would be a valid option (i.e. s=1)? As for modifying the implementation, would I do it so that instead of just looking at which rows/columns need to be covered, I make it check more squares as well, which then checks the usual row/column/square constraint etc? Sorry if that seems like a basic thing, it's a lot to take in :P

Comment: @Opaquer yes, that how the slack variables work. You don't want to choose constraints with them to branch on because it tends to (always?) makes the search tree bigger. The optimization to using a flag on the constraint instead of a slack variable makes things tidier.

Comment: Right, so far it's making sense. It definitely sounds like the constraint is the better option for the variations I've got then instead of the slack variable - basically all I'd do is make it so that if square 1,7 is a 5, remove all rows of the matrix where x255=1 too, no? I think now the only hard bit now is actually coding it :-P! I usually learn best by example, so I might have to find some code that's already out there for this type of thing, then figure out how to make it apply to all the different variations of sudoku I've got planned already...